# Attach STL to object with gravity for best fit

Tags: snapping

Hi I am an orthodontist (I straighten teeth with braces). I have an stl file of a brace and I want to attach it to an stl file of tooth. I want the simulate gravity of the brace along it's z axis so as to achieve a best fit. I am wondering if somebody could help me. Perhaps there is a better way also.

I will donate to anybody that can help me or a charity of their choice. Thank You.

Comment: Please don't offer donations on Blender StackExchange.

Comment: There may be a better way; it depends on the problem. Is the brace allowed to / expected to deform? Or are you looking for the best fit between rigid objects? An illustration, at least of the principle,  would help.

Comment: I apologize I did not know, the brace cannot deform, but the air gap which should be as low as possible can be filled. The best fit between 2 rigid objects is desirable but the brace should not be allow to rotate on the y axis.